# How to reference cells relatively in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quicktable in an excel 2013 sheet (a table with headers which can be filtered).
In vba, I know how to get the value of a cell by using something like Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12).Value
but what if I want to get the active row's cell under a column with a specific name, such as "CUSTOMER NAME" heading. Not column A, or B, or C, or 1, 2, or 3, but the self-described name of the column. Is it possible? The reasoning - if I later relocate this column to a different order in the table, the reference will still be correct in VBA.

Comment: You can reference your Table using a `ListObject` and a column by name with `ListColums("ColumnName")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim lstObj As ListObject
Dim rColumn As Range

' Get the table reference
Set lstObj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

' Get the column reference
Set rColumn = lstObj.ListColumns("Field1").DataBodyRange

' display first data value in the column
MsgBox rColumn(1).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data is in a table and setup named ranges in your workbook then you can refer to those as ranges in your vba with something like this:

```
     MyWorksheet.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your range is only 1 cell, then `MyWorksheet.Range("MyNamedRange")` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use the Range.Find() method in order to dynamically search for a column. This allows you to avoid using ListObjects (though I always do format my data into ListObjects for other purposes). The below code allows you a quick and dynamic way of finding your specified column:

```
Sub DynamicColumn()
Dim r As Range                              ' Stores the range to find
Dim ws As Worksheet                         ' Stores the current ws

Dim iColumn As Integer                      ' Variable to store the column #.


' I use "ThisWorkbook" to qualify all of my worksheet references, or I set a
' workbook variable to "ThisWorkbook". This just helps prevent accidental references
' to other workbooks.

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")

' Search the worksheet for "TextToFind" and assign it to the r variable.
' There are additional arguments for the find method that you can find on MSDN.


Set r = ws.Cells.Find("TextToFind")


' If you only want to search in the (x) row, use this version.
' Set r = ws.Rows(x).Find("AlternativeSearch")

' Get the column number of your header.

' The "Is Not" "Is Nothing" statement tripped me up for a while. Basically,
' when we "Not" r, we are flipping it. If it contains a value it becomes
' nothing, if it doesn't contain a value then it skips the statement without
' raising an error.

If Not r Is Nothing Then iColumn = r.Column

End Sub
```

Your column number is then stored within the iColumn variable. You can also just refer to "r.Column" and use other methods of the range variable.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Realized after the fact that this thread is old. My apologies!